# Choosing PHP function in HTML form

Tags: php, html, ajax

I just read this [tutorial](https://jonsuh.com/blog/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return/) and I need some help.

In the example the HTML always call the same function in the PHP, the "test_function" function, but I'd like to call a different function depending on the values of the HTML form.

I tried this but didn't work:

```
<?php
if (is_ajax()) {
  if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $action = $data["favorite_beverage"];
    switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
      case "test": test_function(); 
      case "testin": testin_function();
      break;
    }
  }
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function test_function(){
  $return = $_POST;

  //Do what you need to do with the info. The following are some examples.
  //if ($return["favorite_beverage"] == ""){
  //  $return["favorite_beverage"] = "Coke";
  //}
  //$return["favorite_restaurant"] = "McDonald's";

  $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
  echo json_encode($return);
}

function testin_function(){

  echo json_encode("You did it !");
}

?>
```

How can I choose another function depending on the "favourite beverage" form field?

Comment: use `switch` properly

Comment: You don't appear to be initialising your `$data` array. You're probably using the wrong variable.

Comment: Read the manual on switch http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Switch with breaks and switch case is based on $POST["action"].

Read the manual on switch http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

```
<?php
if (is_ajax()) {
  if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $action = $POST["action"];
    switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
        case "test": 
            test_function(); 
            break;
        case "testin": 
            testin_function();
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

b) adjust data to have an action, based on the value of the beverage form field

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
  $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){

    // serialize the form
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    // append action - set to the value of the favourite_beverage form field
    data = data + "&action=" + data["favorite_beverage"];

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "response.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        $(".the-return").html(
          "Favorite beverage: " + data["favorite_beverage"] + "<br />Favorite restaurant: " + data["favorite_restaurant"] + "<br />Gender: " + data["gender"] + "<br />JSON: " + data["json"]
        );

        alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

You are still passing the form values from client-side (JS) to PHP.
Additionally you are passing an "action" with the value of the form field "favourite_beverage".

This is the action for your switch statement on PHP side.
If the favourite_beverage form field is testin, then the passed in action is testin and the function testin_function() will be executed.

Comment: that isn't the only thing wrong with the OP's code. Read the comments under their question about their use of switch. It requires a break on each.

Comment: The switch is not the problem, because $data is not there.. no $data, no case to switch.

Comment: it's "part" of the problem. See for yourself http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php and OP has no break between both function calls they wish to call seperately.

Comment: Sure, it's part of the problem, but i see the focus more on the "jQuery form.serialize() with other parameters" issue. Hope my answer fits for the OP. Let's see...

Comment: Let's see what the OP has to say. Let's hope it fixes it, *cheers*

Comment: Thanks guys, I just needed how to select a different function depending of the imput of the users and you solve it.

Comment: Hey guys, I'm sorry but didn't worked :/ This is how my 2 files are and I think I just changed what Jens said:

HTML: http://pastebin.com/KNZsdgWE
PHP: http://pastebin.com/FnLN0WmV

I asumed it had to do the same that did before but just when I set favourite_beverage as test or testin.